# Как в C# объединить несколько картинок в одну?

Tags: c#

Например есть 9 *.JPG картинок с одинаковым разрешением (пусть 500х500), и мне нужно:

1. Объединить их в матрицу 3х3
2. Уменьшить разрешение матрицы до 1000х1000
3. Сохранить в файл

Как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Comment: Возьмите библиотеку графическую GdiPlus например, изучите справку про неё, MSDN почитайте. Возможностей библиотеки для вас будет достаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private List<Bitmap> images;
private int imageWidth, imageHeight, matrixSize;
private Bitmap newImage;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    imageWidth = 500;
    imageHeight = 500;
    matrixSize = 3;
    newImage = new Bitmap(imageWidth * matrixSize, imageHeight * matrixSize);
    newImage.SetResolution(72, 72);

    images = new List<Bitmap>()
    {
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img1.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img2.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img3.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img4.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img5.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img6.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img7.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img8.png"),
        new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\img9.png")
    };

    // 1. Объединить их в матрицу 3х3            
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
    for (int y = 0, count = 0; y < imageHeight * matrixSize; y += 500)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth * matrixSize; x += 500)
        {
            g.DrawImage(images[count], x, y);
            count++;
        }
    }

    // 2. Уменьшить разрешение матрицы до 1000х1000
    newImage = ResizeImage(newImage, 1000, 1000);

    // 3. Сохранить в файл
    newImage.Save("C:\\Users\\Jagailo\\Desktop\\matrix.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Для изменения размера использовал метод из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199315/5998235):

```
public Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень пригодилось. Единственное, непонятна строчка: newImage.SetResolution(72, 72); - именно при значении 72 изображения склеиваются нормально, однако если поменять эти параметры, происходят перекосы

Comment: Это разрешение изображения. DPI, пиксели на дюйм, по стандарту это 72. [Пример](https://i.imgur.com/1uUzM2w.png). Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос - отметьте этот ответ как правильный.